# Stripe.js was not loaded correctly

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I'm loading stripe into my payment page like so:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

This works perfectly in my local test environment but in production, the following console error appears:

```
Uncaught Error: It looks like Stripe.js was not loaded correctly
    at new e (controller-84824401a25a5595fc578f767b4d5c27.js:1)
    at controller-84824401a25a5595fc578f767b4d5c27.js:1
    at Object.bnjt (controller-84824401a25a5595fc578f767b4d5c27.js:1)
    at t (shared-d3604a85e14ef273096e09821a0e4c2a.js:1)
    at Object.3 (controller-84824401a25a5595fc578f767b4d5c27.js:1)
    at t (shared-d3604a85e14ef273096e09821a0e4c2a.js:1)
    at window.webpackJsonp (shared-d3604a85e14ef273096e09821a0e4c2a.js:1)
    at controller-84824401a25a5595fc578f767b4d5c27.js:1
```

I can't work out what might be causing the error. I'm using HTTPS in production and can see the JS file source downloading successfully. Any tips?

Comment: Solved following advice from @NathanCasebolt:

Answer (score 3):

Solved following advice from @NathanCasebolt. SO mods deleted his original answer:

> “For me, the resolution to this error was as simple as spell-checking
>   my variables. In my backend server code, one of my variables was
>   wrongly capitalized. Since the misspelled variable was part of the
>   function that retrieves my publishable key, the key returned from the
>   server as null. This, in turn, disrupted creation of the Stripe object
>   and threw this error. If I were you, I'd check to make sure (1) that
>   the publishable key on your frontend matches the publishable key in
>   your dashboard, and (2) that you're not doing anything that might
>   disrupt serving this key to Stripe.”
>
> The StackOverflow mods felt this didn’t answer the question and
>   required too much clarification. So, to clarify, the problem for me
>   was this line:
>
> var stripe = Stripe(‘{PUBLISHABLE_KEY}’);
>
> I set things up to retrieve my publishable keys from my server, to
>   give me more flexibility in switching between test keys and live keys.
>   Since my one of my server variables was wrong, I was providing Stripe
>   with a bad key (no key, really), and that’s what threw the error. This
>   is why I suggest you check the publishable key you’re using to create
>   the Stripe object, to make sure that the one you’re using to create
>   the object is there, and that it matches the publishable key you have
>   on your Stripe dashboard."

In my case, this is exactly what I'd done wrong: provided an empty publishable key when initialising Stripe. Ultimately a very simple mistake compounded Stripe's obtuse error message.

Comment: For anybody wandering in here from a search engine like I did, I had the same error, but in my case it was caused by a Chrome extension called [ClearUrls](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clearurls/lckanjgmijmafbedllaakclkaicjfmnk). Be sure to double check in an incognito window to rule out browser extensions.